# SQLite CodeFirst example

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I try to run a CodeFirst example for Entity Framwork with SQLite.
The NuGet Package SQLite.CodeFirst is installed and runs without errors
but it doesn´t create a SQLite DB.
This is my code:

```
using SQLite.CodeFirst;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Text;

namespace EF6SqliteExample
{
    class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var model = modelBuilder.Build(Database.Connection);
            ISqlGenerator sqlGenerator = new SqliteSqlGenerator();
            string sql = sqlGenerator.Generate(model.StoreModel);
        }
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new MyContext())
            {
                var person = new Person() { Name = "John" };
                db.Persons.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Connection-String is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="data source=.\MyDB.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DbContext` class has a method called `.Migrate()` which will go through the migrations pipeline and create your database if it does not already exist.

Here's a source: [Entity Framework Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#applying-migrations-at-runtime)

Comment: I´m sorry but Datebase.Migrate() does not exist in this framework :-(

Comment: Then another option you can try is create the database yourself using the migration tools.
Open up your `Package Manager Console` and type the following:
`> enable-migrations`
`> add-migration "Name you want"` This will create a Migrations folder in your project with the scaffolding required to build the database schema, you don't have to touch the files in that folder.
Finally run `> update-database` to create the database using the migrations previously created.

Comment: I did and where can I find the DB?

Comment: If it doesn't show up in you project files, check the `bin` folder of your project. Or just search for the file inside the project folder using the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

What I pointed out in your code is, `constructor` of class `MyContext` is missing in your code. Add contructor with base and try again.

```
public MyContext() : base("MyDB")
{
   
}
```

after adding constructor in your class, if the `Migrations` folder is not available yet in your project, you have to write some command as below:

1. In your visual studio, go to  `view -> other windows -> package manager console`
2. To enable migration, run `enable-migrations` . After executing it, you will find Migrations folder.
3. now add migration with message for current project, run `add-migration InitialCreate`
4. to update Database, run `update-database`

Refresh/Reconnect you server/db. You will find the db there.